# Difficulties of convergence of the partial sums of the Fourier inversion formula

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Define the Fourier inversion formula over $\mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$
f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{2\pi ix\cdot\xi}\hat{f}d\xi
$$
where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform over $\mathbb{R}^n$
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}f(x)dx.
$$
of $f$. Define the partial sums of $f$ as 
$$
S_Nf(x)=\int_{|\xi|\leq R}e^{2\pi ix\cdot \xi}\hat{f}(\xi)d\xi.
$$
A famous question in harmonic analysis is the convergence of of the partial sums to $f$ in $L^p$ norm, specifically
$$
S_Nf\to f~\text{in}~L^p~\text{norm}?
$$
I have two questions:

$\textbf{Question 1}:$ Why is pointwise convergence so difficult especially in higher dimensions? I have studied papers whose lone purpose is to establish pointwise convergence using tools such as spherical means and spectral measure but I do not understand why pointwise convergence is so complicated.

$\textbf{Question 2}:$ Why is weak convergence trivial/no issue? What information is present that means we do not have to worry about weak convergence?

Thank you in advance for your comments and assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Young's and Holder's inequalities make weak convergence easy to study, but the pointwise convergence depends on the behaviour of a maximal operator (the Carleson operator) for which it is not that easy to provide effective upper bounds. Carleson's greatest idea was probably to modify usual decomposition techniques in the Calderon-Zygmund theory in the following way:

1. Instead of using a spatial decomposition only, using a decomposition of the space-frequency plane in terms of dyadic tiles of unit area (that accounts for the Heisenberg indetermination principle);
2. Considering the translation, dilation and modulation operators;
3. Approximate the projection operator on the negative frequencies in terms of the previous operators and decomposition;
4. Provide effective bounds from combinatorial arguments.

To carry this plan on in full detail is not an easy task.

We may regard the Carleson's theorem as the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), in particular the weak $L^1$-estimates for the Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator, under steroids. Heavy steroids.

A recommended lecture is [this brilliant piece of work](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307008) of Lacey.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I have used up my votes today so I will upvote it tomorrow!